# 404 redirect with error referrer

Tags: http-status-code-404

I'm looking for a way to have a 404 redirect to the homepage with adding the error to track what's missing.

Something like this:

> http://www.example.com/?error=http://www.example.com/notfoundpath

How to di this?
Cheers

Comment: I don't think it is actually possible. Many browsers of today handle the HTTP error codes internally, like google chrome with its own error page

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Readout the $_REQUEST vars and save them. :-)

Then redirect in the .php file with: header ("Location:/index.php");